# Woocommerce Get Value of Custom Field in Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a custom field in woocomerce checkout page created by this plugin [Checkout Field Editor (Checkout Manager) for WooCommerce](https://ar.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/)

[image]

now im trying to send request after client place an order with order data and that custom field

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $data  = $order->get_data(); // The Order data

    if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) { 
            $url = "https://webhook.site/cb7a8476-72e5-422a-99fb-ca41fb39726d";
            $response = wp_remote_post(
                $url,
                array(
                    'body' => array(
                        'clientref' => $order->get_id(),
                        'name' =>  $order->get_shipping_first_name() ,
                        'area' =>  $data['billing']['area'], // custom field 
                        'uname' =>  "uname",
                        'upass' =>  "upass",
           
                    )
                )
            );
    }
});
```

The request was sent successfully but without this custom field
i think the problem with accessing this custom filed data in this line

```
'area' =>  $data['billing']['area']
```

I tried to access that filed in more than one way and it didnt work

any ideas to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Found this question on WordPress support [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-get-the-value-from-custom-field-using-php-function/)
the answer is

`get_post_meta($order_id, 'field_name', true)`

i replaced that line with that line

```
'area' =>  $data['billing']['area']
```

and the prroblem is solved